# Quadratic variation of logarithm of Bessel process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, quadratic-variation

I am currently looking at the exposition of the Bessel process given in Bass, *Stochastic Processes*, chapter 24 (page  200 onwards).

The squared Bessel process of order $\nu  \geq 0$ starting as $y$ is defined as satisfying the SDE:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d} Y_t = 2\sqrt{Y_t}\mathrm{d}W_t + \nu\,\mathrm{d}t && Y_0 = y
\end{align*} 
$$

In proposition 24.7, it is claimed that for $\nu = 2$, the quadratic variation of $\log Y$ up to $t$ is $\int_0^t\!\mathrm{d}s\,Y_s^{-2}$. Yet, from the following calculation:
$$
\begin{align*} 
\mathrm{d} \log Y_t & = \frac{\mathrm{d} Y_t} {Y_t} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\langle Y \rangle_t}{Y_t^2}\\
& = \frac{2}{\sqrt{Y_t}}\mathrm{d}W_t + \frac{\nu - 2}{Y_t}\mathrm{d}t\\
& = \frac{2}{\sqrt{Y_t}}\mathrm{d}W_t
\end{align*} 
$$
I rather find $4\int_0^t\!\mathrm{d}s\,Y_s^{-1}$. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they meant that the log of the Bessel process define as $R_t = Y_t^2$ has this particular quadratic variation.

Indeed, we know that the dynamic of $R_t$ is
\begin{equation}
dR_t = dW_t +\frac{\nu-1}{2}\frac{1}{R_t}dt
\end{equation}
Therefore, we have by Ito's lemma: 
\begin{equation}
d\log(R_t) = \frac{1}{R_t}dW_t 
\end{equation}
You can see the quadratic variation of the above process is$\int_0^t\!\mathrm{d}s\,R_s^{-2}$.